# Demo Application to create Kafka Producer throws "Failed to construct kafka producer" error for java.lang.InstantiationException: null

Tags: spring, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am writing a demo application to create a Kafka Producer. I created a topic and ran a producer and consumer on Kafka, it seems to be working. I am writing a spring application to create a producer.I'm passing the name as part of the call. When I go to "http://localhost:8080/kafka/publish/Peter",  I'm getting a whitelabel error "Failed to construct kafka producer". Please help.

The main application is:
SpringBootKafkaProducerApplication.java

```
package com.ranjana.demo.kafka.springbootkafkaproducer;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootKafkaProducerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootKafkaProducerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The model is :
User.java

```
package com.ranjana.demo.kafka.springbootkafkaproducer.model;

public class User {
    private String name;
    private String Department;
    private Long Salary;

    public User(String name, String department, Long salary) {
        this.name = name;
        Department = department;
        Salary = salary;
    }

    //Getters and setters

}
```

The controller is UserResourse.java

```
package com.ranjana.demo.kafka.springbootkafkaproducer.resource;

import com.ranjana.demo.kafka.springbootkafkaproducer.model.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("kafka")
public class UserResource {
    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate;
    private static final String TOPIC = "demo_topic";

    @GetMapping("/publish/{name}")
    public String post(@PathVariable("name") final String name){
        kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, new User(name, "Technology", 12000L));
        return "Published Successfully";
    }
}
```

There is also this configuration file:
KafkaConfiguration.java

```
package com.ranjana.demo.kafka.springbootkafkaproducer.config;

import com.ranjana.demo.kafka.springbootkafkaproducer.model.User;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, User> producerFactory(){
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate(){
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

My application.properties has:

```
server.port=8080
```

The error on http://localhost:8080/kafka/publish/Peter is:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Aug 09 12:36:10 CDT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Failed to construct kafka producer
```

Also the console shows:

```
"/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=56874:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/ranjanasinha/ransinha/spring-boot-kafka-producer/target/classes:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.11.2/log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.11.2/log4j-api-2.11.2.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.26/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.23/snakeyaml-1.23.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.9/jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.9.9/jackson-core-2.9.9.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.9/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.9.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.9/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.9.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.9.9/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.9.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.22/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.22/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.22.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.22/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.22.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.17.Final/hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.2.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.4.0/classmate-1.4.0.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/kafka/spring-kafka/2.2.8.RELEASE/spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-messaging/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-messaging-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/retry/spring-retry/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-retry-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/2.0.1/kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/lz4/lz4-java/1.4.1/lz4-java-1.4.1.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.1.7.1/snappy-java-1.1.7.1.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.26/slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ranjanasinha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar com.ranjana.demo.kafka.springbootkafkaproducer.SpringBootKafkaProducerApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.7.RELEASE)

2019-08-09 12:50:39.250  INFO 14006 --- [           main] d.k.s.SpringBootKafkaProducerApplication : Starting SpringBootKafkaProducerApplication on Egens-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 14006 (/Users/ranjanasinha/ransinha/spring-boot-kafka-producer/target/classes started by ranjanasinha in /Users/ranjanasinha/ransinha/spring-boot-kafka-producer)
2019-08-09 12:50:39.252  INFO 14006 --- [           main] d.k.s.SpringBootKafkaProducerApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-09 12:50:39.776  INFO 14006 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62e8d338] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-08-09 12:50:39.964  INFO 14006 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-08-09 12:50:39.985  INFO 14006 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-08-09 12:50:39.985  INFO 14006 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.22]
2019-08-09 12:50:40.044  INFO 14006 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-08-09 12:50:40.044  INFO 14006 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 755 ms
2019-08-09 12:50:40.235  INFO 14006 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-08-09 12:50:40.410  INFO 14006 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-08-09 12:50:40.415  INFO 14006 --- [           main] d.k.s.SpringBootKafkaProducerApplication : Started SpringBootKafkaProducerApplication in 1.383 seconds (JVM running for 6.925)
2019-08-09 12:50:50.531  INFO 14006 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-08-09 12:50:50.531  INFO 14006 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-08-09 12:50:50.536  INFO 14006 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 5 ms
2019-08-09 12:50:50.565  INFO 14006 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [127.0.0.1:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer

2019-08-09 12:50:50.572  INFO 14006 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
2019-08-09 12:50:50.581 ERROR 14006 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer] with root cause

java.lang.InstantiationException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:306) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:302) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:370) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:289) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.createKafkaProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:318) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.createProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:305) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.getTheProducer(KafkaTemplate.java:448) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:378) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:193) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.ranjana.demo.kafka.springbootkafkaproducer.resource.UserResource.post(UserResource.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

And the pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.egen.demo.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-kafka-producer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-kafka-producer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your console logs
value.serializer = class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer

Instead of the serializer from jackson use org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

An exception is occurring when trying to construct the instance of the class corresponding to VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG property.

The value of VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG must be a class which implements the org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer interface.

jackson.databind.JsonSerializer doesn't satisfy this criteria  and results in an InstantiationException. So use org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer which implements the above mentioned Serializer interface.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I figured it out and forgot to update it.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through this issue once I started learning Kafka

**What is the issue here:**
Wrong JsonSerializer class has been imported by the IDE.

**What to Do:**
When ever you are constructing object ProducerFactory, make sure that you are importing correct class file. In this case, when you write JsonSerializer.class then by default IDE may pick wrong classes hence we need to correct JsonSerializer.class

so import of JsonSerializer.class in this as below `config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);`

and it must be  `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer` instead of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer`

Happy Coding!!